# CSS: Expand div upwards when height is changed?

Tags: css, html

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="total">
        <span class="current"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css of the above 4 tags:

```
.progress
{
    margin-top: -5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #090605;
}

.total
{
    background-color: #221F1E;
    border-top: 1px solid #2F2F2F;
    height: 2px;
}
    .hover
    {
        margin-top: -8px;
        height: 5px;
    }

.current
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    height: 100%;
    color: blue;
}
```

**I manipulate the height of `.total` in a hover event.**

I can't find a way to make `.total` to expand up when I change the height from `2px` to `5px` on hover. When I change the height now, it works, it expands down by `3px` and shrinks by `3px` when the mouse leaves.

I want it to expand **up** instead of down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use hover, you must do it this way:
`.total:hover{margin-top: -8px;
        height: 5px;}`

However, you must remember that the normal flow of a document is top to down. To make a lower level div expand upward, you may need to shrink the element above it. Something accomplished only with javascript in most cases.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, albeit using a parent div.

Comment: +1 this is better then my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3z4/) of positioning absolutely inside the parent and adjusting height and top/bottom on hover etc

Answer (score 2):

It also works if you just play with the `bottom` property. This tells where the bottom starts so it will stay fixed at the specified position and it'll expand upward if needed.

Comment: Brilliant! Never thought of that in detail but you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make .total position relative to upper element. And when mouse hovers, you change the top margin

With JQuery you can do something like:

```
$(".total").hover(
  function () {
    $('.total').css('margin-top','-8px');
    $('.total').css('height','5px');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('.total').css('margin-top','0px');
    $('.total').css('height','2px');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try negative values? `-5px`

Comment: There's a border that interferes with the hover when I use negative values, so I don't want to use them.